# parsley.js - data-parsley-errors-container

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I am trying to use the errors container (eg data-parsley-errors-container="#ErrorSummary") with parsely.js.

I have everything working, however, I hit a snag.

I only want to set the background color of the div to a shade of red. I can do this with CSS but then the div is visible even with no errors in it.

I have tried hiding the div when the page is first opened. But then it isnt displayed when there are errors.

Is there a way to hide the error container div when the page is first opened and then show it if errors are found?

Answer (score 1):

When the error container contains any errors the element should have a class added to it called "filled". You could add your styles only if that class is present on the container.

My error container looks something like this when it's filled with an error.

```
<div class="parsley-container filled">
    <div class="parsley-required">This field is required</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parsleyConfig = {
    errorsContainer: function(pEle) {
        var $err = pEle.$element.find("div.parsley_container");
        return $err;
    }
};

jQuery("#form").parsley(parsleyConfig);
```